# Gradle build failed : could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin even if I haven't used Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle

I am creating an app in Android Studio IDE using Java, but whenever I build my project this error comes:

```
Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.10.
Required by:
    project :app
```

I have checked all the previous answers, but they are outdated. I haven't even used Kotlin anywhere but despite of that, this error comes.
Here's my app level Gradle code:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.safechat"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0'

}
```

and below is my project level Gradle code:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Please help because I cannot develop further features without testing older features. (The line 8 in project level Gradle file causes errors on being removed, so I am bound to keep it)

Edit 1 - Removed a confusing line from the code here as well as in my own file, didn't make any difference.

Edit 2 - Added a necessary line for more clarification.

Comment: Pay attention to the last line of `dependencies` in your app level Gradle file.

Comment: @GenoChen I've written that line trying to resolve the error myself, as I thought adding that dependency will resolve the issue but it didn't. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add jcenter() to your repositories

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
         classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }
```

Also add java 11 to your project

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, that helped me as well for latest update on Android Studio with Java 11

Comment: For any Maven packages published after March 31st, 2021, this won't be the best answer anymore. JCenter is [not maintained](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/jcenter-migration) anymore. It has become read-only. The recommendation is to switch to Maven Central.

Comment: Yes, quick update: now we should use mavenCentral()

Answer (score 3):

Replace `jcenter()` with `mavenCentral()`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: JCenter is [not maintained](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/jcenter-migration) anymore. It has become read-only for packages updated prior to March 31st, 2021. Anything newer than that won't be found there, which is the case with `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.10`. The recommendation is to switch to Maven Central.

Answer (score 0):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

add this line in your root level build.gradle